# How to use pairwise comparison lines in a grouped plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create pairwise comparison lines within a grouped plot. I can create the lines in an ungrouped plot like this:

```
df <- iris %>%
        group_by(Species) %>%
        mutate(Pairs = row_number()) %>%
        gather(variable, value, -c(Species, Pairs)) %>%
        filter(variable == "Petal.Length")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Species, y = value, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = Pairs), color = "#444444")
```

But if I try to group the data by `variable` (which would allow me to potentially plot multiple grouped variables), the lines do not connect correctly but appear to be the correct length:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.7)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Pairs), color = "#444444")
```

The benefit of plotting this way is that I can plot multiple variables and keep them grouped together.

```
df2 <- iris %>%
            group_by(Species) %>%
            mutate(Pairs = row_number()) %>%
            gather(variable, value, -c(Species, Pairs)) %>%
            filter(variable %in% c("Petal.Length", "Sepal.Length"))

ggplot(df2, aes(x = variable, y = value, color = Species)) +
      geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.7)) +
      geom_line(aes(group = Pairs), color = "#444444")
```

Is there a way to get the lines to connect to their respective points?

The variables (e.g., `Sepal.Length`, `Petal.Length`, etc...) are plotted on the x-axis and grouped together such that the values from `Sepal.Length` are not being mixed up with the values from `Petal.Length` even if both variables are plotted. The comparisons in these plots are the same as in the first plot (i.e., by `Species`). I have created a column called `Pairs` that contains a number for each individual sample. I would like to use the information in `Pairs` to link the individual points from each `Species` together with a connecting line as is the case in the first plot above.

Comment: In the x-axis you only have one value ("Petal.Length"), there is nothing to connect

Comment: @SRivero I would like the lines to connect the paired points between the `Species` (grouping variable) the way they are connected when I use `Species` as the x-axis variable in the first plot.

Comment: What I am trying to said is that there are not paired points in your data with variables in the x-axis

Comment: @SRivero I understand that there is only a single x-axis variable but I am grouping the data by `Species` which contains 3 members. I would like to display comparison lines connecting the paired points (based on the values in the `Pairs` column). Is your point that `geom_line()` is not going to work without x-axis variables?

Comment: Yes, `geom_line` will  not work without x-axis variables because to draw a line you need at least 2 points

Comment: @SRivero Any way to use a different geom to do the trick?

Comment: I don't know, I really don't get what you want to plot. Also your concept of groups is hard to understand

Comment: @SRivero I updated the question to try to clarify what it is that I am trying to do. Thanks for your help!